# How to Create a Search Bar To search for Images or Text Without a Database in android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, database, string

I am trying to create a search box that can help locate images from the mipmap-xxxhdpi folder or a search box that can locate the strings being used in the layout without a database  compilesdkversion is 29 and min sdk version is 15

```
ListingPage.java

public class ListingsPage extends MainActivity   {





    Button b1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listings_grid);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListingsPage.this, malaysia_kit.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

     .......
.......
.......

    }

}
```

have included multiple buttons in above code

```
[malaysiakit][1]


malaysia_kit.xml

<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/malaysialogo"
            android:editable="false"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:editable="false"
            android:text="Malaysia Kits"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF8DC"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:text="Explore Kits"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF8DC"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listbutton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_id" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/malaysialogo"
        android:editable="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:text="Barcelona Kits"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF8DC"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`enter code here`
</ScrollView>
```

above is the code with the logo and string